# For a class to use CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, it has to have a context correct?

Tags: asp.net, localization, culture

If a class library method references CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, the calling client has to be running with a HttpContext correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. No need. Works in Windows apps, console apps, anywhere.